# What's wrong with my iterative backtracking algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, iteration, backtracking

So I am working on an iterative backtracking algorithm to solve this task:

> Generate all subsequences of length 2n+1, formed only by 0, -1 or 1, such that a<sub>1</sub> = 0, ..., a<sub>2n+1</sub>= 0 and |a<sub>i+1</sub> - a<sub>i</sub>| = 1 or 2, for any 1 ≤ i ≤ 2n.

This is what I tried:

```
def is_ok(list, k):
    for i in range(1, k + 1):
        if abs(list[i] - list[i-1]) == 0:
            return False
    if k == len(list)-2:
        if abs(list[k+1]-list[k]) == 0:
            return False
    return True

def back_iter(n):
    list_size = n*2+1
    solution = [-1] * list_size
    solution[0] = 0
    solution[2*n] = 0
    position = 1
    while position >= 1:
        if is_ok(solution, position) and position < 2*n-1:
            if position == 2*n-2:
                print(solution)

            position += 1
            solution[position] = -1
        else:
            while solution[position] == 1:
                solution[position] = -1
                position -= 1
            if position < 1:
                break
            solution[position] += 1
```

My output for n=2:

```
[0, -1, 0, -1, 0]
[0, -1, 1, -1, 0]
[0, 1, -1, -1, 0]
[0, 1, 0, -1, 0]
```

Expected output for n=2:

```
[0, -1, 0, -1, 0]
[0, -1, 0, 1, 0]
[0, -1, 1, -1, 0]
[0, 1, -1, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 0, -1, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

Comment: Did you do any [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)?

Comment: Yes, back when the if statement didn't include "and position < 2*n-1". Back then the problem was that the position kept increasing and it exceeded the list size. I can not figure the problem now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

everything is correct in your code, but you are printing at wrong place

```
def is_ok(arr, i):
    return abs(arr[i]-arr[i-1]) in (1,2)

def back_iter(n):
    list_size = n*2+1
    solution = [-1] * list_size
    solution[0] = 0
    solution[2*n] = 0
    position = 1
    while position >= 1:
        
        if is_ok(solution, position) and position < 2*n-1:
            position += 1
            solution[position] = -1
          
        else:
            if is_ok(solution, position) and position == (2*n-1) and solution[position]:
                print(solution)
            while solution[position] == 1:
                solution[position] = -1
                position -= 1
            
            if position < 1:
                break
            solution[position] += 1
            

back_iter(2)

# output 
[0, -1, 0, -1, 0]
[0, -1, 0, 1, 0]
[0, -1, 1, -1, 0]
[0, 1, -1, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 0, -1, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```